# Download Speed is slow in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-download-manager

I have a list of PDFs that I need to download all PDFs in one click. I have implemented a foreground service to do the task. In this service I am enqueuing the list of PDFs in the Android DownloadManager's request to handle the downloads.

For the enqueue of request, I am inserting 6 PDF's in request for the first time and further when any one download completed I am inserting next PDF in the request list.

In this implementation the whole process is taking around 1-2 mins for the 91 PDFs(roughly size of 40MB in total). Is there any way, so we can speed up the download process.

This is the function to start Download queue

```
private void startDownloadQueue() 
{
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(i<hashMap.size()) {
            listIndex++;
            initiateDownload(documentList.get(i), positionList.get(i), hashMap.size());
        }
    }
}


private void initiateDownload(DocumentJsonModel.Document doc, int pos, int listSize)
{
    if (doc != null && isDownloading) {
        String position = String.valueOf(pos);
        String docId = doc.id;
        String docFile = doc.file;
        String docName = doc.name;
        String docDescription = doc.description;
        boolean isJustView = false;
        isFromSearch = false;

        long id = downloadFile(doc, docId, docFile, docName, docDescription, position, isJustView, listSize);
        if (id != 0) {
            setProgressUpdate(id, Integer.parseInt(position), Integer.parseInt(docId), isJustView, doc, listSize);
        } else if (isJustView) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(INTENT_FILTER_ACTION_OPEN_DOC);
            intent1.putExtra("docID",docId);
            intent1.putExtra("position",pos);
            intent1.putExtra("fromDownloadAll", true);
            intent1.putExtra("docId", docId);
            sendBroadcast(intent1);
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        } else if (isFromSearch) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(INTENT_FILTER_ACTION_OPEN_DOC_FROM_SEARCH);
            intent1.putExtra("fromDownloadAll", true);
            intent1.putExtra("position", pos);
            intent1.putExtra("docId", docId);
            sendBroadcast(intent1);
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```

Method to enqueue PDFs in download manager request queue -

```
public long downloadFile(DocumentJsonModel.Document doc,String docId, String docFile, String docName, String description, String position, boolean isJustView, int listSize) {
    long downloadReference = 0;
    String root = "/twoway/saved_documents/";
    String BASE_DIR = getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();

    File dir = new File(BASE_DIR + root);
    File file = new File(dir, docId + "_" + docFile);
    if(!isCancelledButtonPressed) {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            String fileUrl = DOCUMENT_URL + docFile;
            fileUrl = fileUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

            Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(fileUrl);
            //Create request for android download manager
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(fileUri);
            //set title for download
            request.setTitle(docName);
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
            //request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION);
            //Setting description of request
            request.setDescription(description);

            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, null, "/twoway/saved_documents/"
                    + docId + "_" + docFile);

            //Enqueue download and save into referenceId
            downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);



        }
```

}}

Comment: You should also tell us the download speed of your internet connection as that is the first thing that determines the .. speed.. and... needed time.

Comment: @blackapps Download speed is around 1-2 MBps

Comment: 40MB in 1-2min's on this speed is fine. There is nothing u could do to make it faster

Comment: @MAshhal Is there any other way or better implementation we can do this task?

Comment: You queue 6 at once. Did you try with one or other amounts? First try one.

Comment: @PrashantKumar U could download the document based on the user, when the user clicks on that documen

Comment: @MAshhal We have that feature separately, This feature is another feature where we need to download all PDFs in one go